# Batch File Use Stdin and Stdout as Files

Tags: cmd, io-redirection

I have a program that is executed from `CMD`:

```
program input.txt output.txt
```

How can I create a batch file that will run `program` so that `input.txt` is actually `stdin` and `output.txt` is actually `stdout`?

I would like to be able to run `program-wrapper.bat`, then give it some input, close it's `stdin` and then see all the output from `program` in the console. `program` will not be able to read the file `input.txt`, and it should not write to the file `output.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ECHO OFF
ECHO Give me some input, terminate with Ctrl-Z and Enter.
COPY CON input.txt >NULL
program input.txt output.txt
TYPE output.txt
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.